# Android AsyncTask not being called for minutes on ICS

Tags: android, android-asynctask, threadpool, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I have an application that uses a lot of AsyncTasks, the problem I have is that a particularly important task is not being started for upto a couple of minutes after I call execute.

If I use the following for my ICS devices it works;

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11)
{
  myTask.executeOnExecutor( AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, stuff );
}
```

as opposed to this on pre-ICS;

```
myTask.execute(stuff);
```

I am aware that ICS has changed thread execution to be serialised but I can't figure out what is holding up the thread queue.

There are about 20 threads listed in debug in eclipse, but I have read around that perhaps this is not correct as the debugger tends to keep displaying ones  that aren't really there.

How do I figure out which threads are holding up the serialised queue so i don't have to switch from the default on ICS, and perhaps even improve performance of pre-ICS devices that arne't seeing the problems due to the thread pool executor being default behaviour.

Comment: Please don't correct my British English to American English, and certainly don't add more typographical errors. :D

Comment: Does it always take the same length of time to start or does it vary?

Comment: it's varied, some times it will execute instantly, as expected, others I will have to wait a couple of minutes. Although there doesn't seem to be an in-between, it's either instant, or x (uncounted) minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I figure out which threads are holding up the serialised queue

Add `Log` statements to track entry and exit from the relevant `doInBackground()` methods.

> and perhaps even improve performance of pre-ICS devices that arne't seeing the problems due to the thread pool executor being default behaviour.

You don't need to use `AsyncTask`. Just fork your own thread and use stuff like `runOnUiThread()` as a means of executing logic back on the main application thread. `AsyncTask` is a convenience, not a requirement. And, for an outlier high-priority task, it may make more sense for you to simply keep that away from any thread pool contention.

Or, clone and fork `AsyncTask` to use a `PriorityQueue`, so you can explicitly indicate your high-priority tasks.

Comment: Thanks CW, I'll put this to test.

Comment: This certainly helped me figure out the cause, it seems one of my AsyncTasks doing comms with a DefaultHttpClient is not finishing for a long time. I have connection and socket timeouts set on this client so can't figure out what's holding up the task, the timouts short, one or two seconds. Also, It appears to only do this on the HTC Sensation with ICS 4.0.3, testing on a Galaxy S2 4.0.3 works fine.